# How can I click a link in a list, scroll back, and click the next subsequent link using selenium in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I want to:

1. Navigate to https://www.sedar.com/issuers/company_issuers_a_en.htm
2. click the first link in the list of companies
3. Enter code that will copy company info, industry, email, etc once I learn how to do that part - but for these purposes I am happy to skip this step and learn about the selenium side first
4. click back
5. click the next link, until I get to the end of the list.

This will ultimately leave me with an excel list of companies and their industries etc.

I have now tried the following:

```
#Step 1 from list above - Navigate to https://www.sedar.com/issuers/company_issuers_a_en.htm

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")

browser.get('https://www.sedar.com/issuers/issuers_en.htm')


#Step 2. from list above - click the first link in the list of companies 

elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#content > map:nth-child(2) > area:nth-child(1)")

elem.click()

results = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"DisplayProfile")]')

results[1].click() #successfully clicked through


#-------
#Step 3 which will scrape and paste into excel - future learning
#-------


#Step 4 from list above - click back
browser.back() #successfully went back


#Step 5 from list above - click the next link, until I get to the end of the list.
results[2].click()
```

Step 5 gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#291>", line 1, in <module>
    results[2].click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

****Update 2****

After looking at your solution realize all I really need is the "content" id from the individual company profiles (for example, the first company at https://www.sedar.com/DisplayProfile.do?lang=EN&issuerType=03&issuerNo=00033802 has the individual things like "Auditor" and "Principal Regulator" that  were attached to "content" from what I can tell in the inspect element).

I noticed it looks like your solution goes right to the main sedar page, and then takes the "display profile" x path, instead of navigating all the way through the urls (I had no idea that was possible) so I figured why not tweak it so it follows the same logic but goes right to the company pages and take the various bits of info such as company name and auditor etc.

Then instead of saving to excel, since I'm having trouble finding good documentation, figured I would save to a single text file and just manually use text to columns in excel later.  (but nothing happens after it loads the sedar web page and there's no error message/no text document I can see when I check my computer).

```py
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")

browser.get('https://www.sedar.com/issuers/issuers_en.htm')

results = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@id,"content")]')

urls = []

for result in results:

    urls.append(result.get_attribute('id'))
    
for url in urls:

    browser.get(url)

    finalsave = contentsofsedar.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your website, you only have 1 element that matches the provided xpath.

The error is not that you cannot click the link the second time, but rather `results[1]` is out of range (i.e. does not exist in your array).

You'll want...

- An xpath that matches all the links: `//a[contains(@href,"DisplayProfile")]`  - for me that is 1280 results
- Then, instead of writing each interaction manually, iterate through your results collection with a for each loop that does (as you have) click, then back

```
for result in results:
    result.click()
    browser.back()
```

If your question is that the `.back()` doesn't work, you can try an alternate method:

```
 browser.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

[update from comments]
You get stale element because the dom has changed and selenium says the object is out of date.

It seems to be around the houses a bit but try this:

```py
#your code
browser.get('https://www.sedar.com/issuers/issuers_en.htm')
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#content > map:nth-child(2) > area:nth-child(1)")
elem.click()

##new code:

results = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"DisplayProfile")]')

#Create a list of URls first so selenium doesn't complain
urls = []
for result in results:
    urls.append(result.get_attribute('href'))


f = open("myfile.txt","a+")

for url in urls:
    #browser.get(url) - temporarily removed to make it run quicker - so you can see file write
    #Do your actions here to get data
    f.write("My data - %s\n" % url) # replace url with that you want to write

f.close()
```

[edit - above updated with file write - when you run it will do all urls so taken out the navigate action to make it run faster]

[output looks like....]

```
My data - https://www.sedar.com/DisplayProfile.do?lang=EN&issuerType=03&issuerNo=00033802
My data - https://www.sedar.com/DisplayProfile.do?lang=EN&issuerType=03&issuerNo=00044563
My data - https://www.sedar.com/DisplayProfile.do?lang=EN&issuerType=03&issuerNo=00009209
My data - https://www.sedar.com/DisplayProfile.do?lang=EN&issuerType=03&issuerNo=00045452
My data - https://www.sedar.com/DisplayProfile.do?lang=EN&issuerType=03&issuerNo=00008912

[...1282 lines in total]
```

Comment: I just updated the post above and would appreciate if you could see what I might be missing.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to press back each tine? Can you just navigate to the hrefs now you have them?  - I'll share some options when I get to my desk...

Comment: What I plan on doing, is I am simultaneously learning how to use excel with python.  So what I want to happen is, for example, when I click the first link, I am going to go back and insert code in there so that when it clicks the link, it will then scrape some info like company name, and industry, and maybe the contact email, and then paste it into excel, then it will click back and go to the next one in the list, copy and paste into excel, then click back.  So I figured I'd put the selenium part together first then excel next  Thanks again!

Comment: As well, I just clarified what I am trying to do above and apologize if it was a bit vague.

Comment: It's great to start automation thinking about the user actions. For testing, that's especially importating however for scraping, just goto each url. There's no need to go back it will half the time the script will take to run

Comment: Thanks again Rich, I took a look at your approach to the previous solution and added an update at the bottom of my post which tried to follow your line of thinking.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I've got a ways to go but appreciate all the help along the way.

Comment: Going a bit off topic from the original question mate - but i've updated the above with a file write...  just google python file write there are loads of examples out there :-)

Comment: Appreciate your help and did not expect the python rabbit hole to be so deep/rewarding to learn!  Will be studying your solution and wish you the best!

Comment: You never know  I could pick up any future questions you post. If this solved your question then mark it as they right answer and job done ;-)